# How to make complicated transformation of string in column based on value of other column?

Tags: r, function, dataframe, join

I have a dataframe:

```
ID          time             value       operation
K1   2020-10-12 07:35:47    K1-0735       create
K1   2020-10-12 07:35:49    K1-0735       upload
K1   2020-10-12 07:35:50    
K1   2020-10-12 07:35:55    K1-0735       create   
K1   2020-10-12 07:35:58    K1-0735       upload
K1   2020-10-12 07:37:19    
KK   2020-10-13 08:11:09    KK-0811       create
KK   2020-10-13 08:11:09    KK-0811       create
KK   2020-10-13 08:11:12    KK-0811       upload       
KK   2020-10-13 08:11:15
KK   2020-10-13 08:11:25    KK-0811       create
KK   2020-10-13 08:11:26    KK-0811       upload
```

As you see column "value" is a join of value of column "ID" and hour and minute from "timestamp" without spaces. I want to add seconds to that value to make it unique within a minute. However they must have same seconds of they are in bundle of "operation" column of values create and upload.

So desired result is:

```
ID          time             value         operation
K1   2020-10-12 07:35:47    K1-073547       create
K1   2020-10-12 07:35:49    K1-073547       upload
K1   2020-10-12 07:35:50    
K1   2020-10-12 07:35:55    K1-073555       create   
K1   2020-10-12 07:35:58    K1-073555       upload
K1   2020-10-12 07:37:19    
KK   2020-10-13 08:11:09    KK-081109       create
KK   2020-10-13 08:11:09    KK-081109       create
KK   2020-10-13 08:11:12    KK-081109       upload       
KK   2020-10-13 08:11:15
KK   2020-10-13 08:11:25    KK-081125       create
KK   2020-10-13 08:11:26    KK-081125       upload
```

How could i do that transformation with the type of condition?

Code to build dataframe:

```
ID <- c("K1","K1","K1","K1","K1","K1","KK","KK","KK","KK","KK","KK")

time <- as.Date(c('2020-10-12 07:35:47','2020-10-12 07:35:49','2020-10-12 07:35:50',
                     '2020-10-12 07:35:55','2020-10-12 07:35:58', '2020-10-12 07:37:19',
                     '2020-10-13 08:11:09','2020-10-13 08:11:09','2020-10-13 08:11:12',
                     '2020-10-13 08:11:15','2020-10-13 08:11:25','2020-10-13 08:11:26'))

value <- c("K1-0735","K1-0735",NA,"K1-0735","K1-0735",NA,"KK-0811","KK-0811","KK-0811",
           NA,"KK-0811","KK-0811")

operation <- c("create", "upload", NA,"create", "upload", NA,"create","create", "upload",
               NA,"create", "upload")
data <- data.frame(ID, time, value,operation)
```

Comment: Hi, quick question, does the value code has 2 letters, then a dash and then time?

Comment: @Tom value consists of value of "ID" column (like KK) dash hour and minute joined without space. So if in a row value in "ID" is K1 and timestamp is 2020-10-12 07:35:47  than value is K1-0735

Comment: is `time` formatted as an actual time variable or as a string? can you provide the example data via `dput`, thanks!

Comment: @starja I added code for creating dataframe. yes time has Date format

Comment: What happens in the case that create and upload are in two different minutes ? e.g, create was on `12:59:10` and upload was `13:00:01` ?

Comment: So...are we correct to assume that `create` entries will always be followed by n `create` up to an `upload`?  And you would want the result to use the minutes and seconds of the first `create` in the bundle ?

Comment: @MatiasAndina yes bundle will always start with "create" and end with "upload". minutes and seconds must be of the first create

Comment: @MatiasAndina case when create was on 12:59:10 and upload was 13:00:01 is possible, upload always has the same hours and minutes as create

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do a lot of this by using the [`rleid`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.13.6/topics/rleid) function from **`data.table`**. I changed your data to be named `dat` instead of `data`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

dat %>%
  mutate(index = rleid(value)) %>%
  group_by(index) %>%
  mutate(min_time = min(time)) %>%
  mutate(value2 = paste0(ID, "-", 
                         str_pad(hour(min_time), 2, pad = 0),
                         str_pad(minute(min_time), 2, pad = 0),
                         str_pad(second(min_time), 2, pad = 0))) %>%
  mutate(value2 = ifelse(is.na(value), NA, value2)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  select(ID, time, value = value2, operation)

   ID    time                value     operation
   <chr> <dttm>              <chr>     <chr>    
 1 K1    2020-10-12 07:35:47 K1-073547 create   
 2 K1    2020-10-12 07:35:49 K1-073547 upload   
 3 K1    2020-10-12 07:35:50 NA        NA       
 4 K1    2020-10-12 07:35:55 K1-073555 create   
 5 K1    2020-10-12 07:35:58 K1-073555 upload   
 6 K1    2020-10-12 07:37:19 NA        NA       
 7 KK    2020-10-13 08:11:09 KK-081109 create   
 8 KK    2020-10-13 08:11:09 KK-081109 create   
 9 KK    2020-10-13 08:11:12 KK-081109 upload   
10 KK    2020-10-13 08:11:15 NA        NA       
11 KK    2020-10-13 08:11:25 KK-081125 create   
12 KK    2020-10-13 08:11:26 KK-081125 upload
```

There is also a solution which will work in the event that the minute is different for the same bundle (which is not covered in your sample data, but could happen). It uses the fact that bundles are separated by a row with `NA`

```
dat %>%
    mutate(row_sep = cumsum(is.na(value))) %>%
    group_by(row_sep) %>%
    mutate(min_time = min(as.POSIXct(ifelse(is.na(value), NA_POSIXct_, time),
                              origin = "1970-01-01 00:00.00 UTC"),
                       na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    mutate(value2 = paste0(ID, "-", 
                           str_pad(hour(min_time), 2, pad = 0),
                           str_pad(minute(min_time), 2, pad = 0),
                           str_pad(second(min_time), 2, pad = 0))) %>%
    mutate(value2 = ifelse(is.na(value), NA, value2)) %>% 
    ungroup() %>%
    select(ID, time, value = value2, operation)

   ID    time                value     operation
   <chr> <dttm>              <chr>     <chr>    
 1 K1    2020-10-12 07:35:47 K1-073547 create   
 2 K1    2020-10-12 07:35:49 K1-073547 upload   
 3 K1    2020-10-12 07:35:50 NA        NA       
 4 K1    2020-10-12 07:35:55 K1-073555 create   
 5 K1    2020-10-12 07:35:58 K1-073555 upload   
 6 K1    2020-10-12 07:37:19 NA        NA       
 7 KK    2020-10-13 08:11:09 KK-081109 create   
 8 KK    2020-10-13 08:11:09 KK-081109 create   
 9 KK    2020-10-13 08:11:12 KK-081109 upload   
10 KK    2020-10-13 08:11:15 NA        NA       
11 KK    2020-10-13 08:11:25 KK-081125 create   
12 KK    2020-10-13 08:11:26 KK-081125 upload
```

Comment: your output doesn't look like desired result. there are no index , min_time ad value2 there

Comment: isn't it more efficient to transform existing column instead of creating new one

Comment: I originally left those columns in there to show the calculation process. I've now removed them to more closely match your desired result

Comment: I think creating a new column results in a more straightforward solution (easier to follow the programmatic breadcrumbs). you are not constrained to work with whatever possible inefficiencies the already existing column(s) contain.

Comment: creating index based on value(index = rleid(value)) is wrong, because we can have two bundles of create upload operation in same minutes but with different seconds, and they will have same index

Comment: aren't bundles separated by a row with `NA` in the `value` column?

Comment: I added another solution, which I think should work in the event you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a somewhat cumbersome approach but I think it can lead you somewhere.

The strategy is to find `start/stop` points in the `operation` vector.

Here's your data, mind that I used `lubridate::as_datetime()` because you used `as.Date()` which removes the timestamp. Also, `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`

```
ID <- c("K1","K1","K1","K1","K1","K1","KK","KK","KK","KK","KK","KK")

time <- lubridate::as_datetime(c('2020-10-12 07:35:47','2020-10-12 07:35:49','2020-10-12 07:35:50',
                  '2020-10-12 07:35:55','2020-10-12 07:35:58', '2020-10-12 07:37:19',
                  '2020-10-13 08:11:09','2020-10-13 08:11:09','2020-10-13 08:11:12',
                  '2020-10-13 08:11:15','2020-10-13 08:11:25','2020-10-13 08:11:26'))

value <- c("K1-0735","K1-0735",NA,"K1-0735","K1-0735",NA,"KK-0811","KK-0811","KK-0811",
           NA,"KK-0811","KK-0811")

operation <- c("create", "upload", NA,"create", "upload", NA,"create","create", "upload",
               NA,"create", "upload")
df <- data.frame(ID, time, value,operation, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

We are going to create the thing

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

# try to find the positions
create_cases <- str_detect(df$operation, "create") %>% which()
upload_cases <- str_detect(df$operation, "upload") %>% which()

# check that they have different lengths and there are contiguous create cases

# check for contiguous create cases
contiguous <- which(diff(create_cases) == 1)
# remove the contiguous cases from the open vector
create_cases <- create_cases[-(contiguous+1)]

# so now we match lengths and we can create ranges in our data frame

# create column in df
df$bundle <- NA
for(i in seq_along(create_cases)){
  df$bundle[create_cases[i]:upload_cases[i]] <- paste0("bundle", i)
}
```

Now we can use grouping to select the seconds properly and paste them

```
df %>% 
  group_by(bundle) %>%
  # get the first of the seconds in the group
  mutate(seconds_to_paste = first(lubridate::second(time)),
         new_id = paste0(value, str_pad(seconds_to_paste, width = 2, pad=0)),
         # clean the NA pasted
         new_id = ifelse(str_detect(new_id, "NA"), NA, new_id))
```

Which produces (I left the extra columns to check everything matches the expected result, you can `select()` the ones you want later)

```
# A tibble: 12 x 7
# Groups:   bundle [5]
   ID    time                value   operation bundle  seconds_to_paste new_id   
   <chr> <dttm>              <chr>   <chr>     <chr>              <dbl> <chr>    
 1 K1    2020-10-12 07:35:47 K1-0735 create    bundle1               47 K1-073547
 2 K1    2020-10-12 07:35:49 K1-0735 upload    bundle1               47 K1-073547
 3 K1    2020-10-12 07:35:50 NA      NA        NA                    50 NA       
 4 K1    2020-10-12 07:35:55 K1-0735 create    bundle2               55 K1-073555
 5 K1    2020-10-12 07:35:58 K1-0735 upload    bundle2               55 K1-073555
 6 K1    2020-10-12 07:37:19 NA      NA        NA                    50 NA       
 7 KK    2020-10-13 08:11:09 KK-0811 create    bundle3                9 KK-081109
 8 KK    2020-10-13 08:11:09 KK-0811 create    bundle3                9 KK-081109
 9 KK    2020-10-13 08:11:12 KK-0811 upload    bundle3                9 KK-081109
10 KK    2020-10-13 08:11:15 NA      NA        NA                    50 NA       
11 KK    2020-10-13 08:11:25 KK-0811 create    bundle4               25 KK-081125
12 KK    2020-10-13 08:11:26 KK-0811 upload    bundle4               25 KK-081125
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach using `pivot_wider` and a self join:

```r
ID <- c("K1","K1","K1","K1","K1","K1","KK","KK","KK","KK","KK","KK")

time <- as.POSIXct(c('2020-10-12 07:35:47','2020-10-12 07:35:49','2020-10-12 07:35:50',
                  '2020-10-12 07:35:55','2020-10-12 07:35:58', '2020-10-12 07:37:19',
                  '2020-10-13 08:11:09','2020-10-13 08:11:09','2020-10-13 08:11:12',
                  '2020-10-13 08:11:15','2020-10-13 08:11:25','2020-10-13 08:11:26'))

value <- c("K1-0735","K1-0735",NA,"K1-0735","K1-0735",NA,"KK-0811","KK-0811","KK-0811",
           NA,"KK-0811","KK-0811")

operation <- c("create", "upload", NA,"create", "upload", NA,"create","create", "upload",
               NA,"create", "upload")
data <- data.frame(ID, time, value,operation)

library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

data %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(ID, value),
              names_from = operation,
              values_from = time) %>%
  unnest(create) %>%
  mutate(value2 = paste0(value, str_pad(second(create), 2, pad = 0))) %>% 
  select(ID, value, create, value2) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  left_join(data, ., by = c("ID", "value", "time" = "create")) %>% 
  mutate(value = case_when(
    !is.na(value2) & !is.na(value) ~ value2,
    !is.na(lag(value2)) & !is.na(value) ~ lag(value2))
    ) %>%
  select(-value2)

#>    ID                time     value operation
#> 1  K1 2020-10-12 07:35:47 K1-073547    create
#> 2  K1 2020-10-12 07:35:49 K1-073547    upload
#> 3  K1 2020-10-12 07:35:50      <NA>      <NA>
#> 4  K1 2020-10-12 07:35:55 K1-073555    create
#> 5  K1 2020-10-12 07:35:58 K1-073555    upload
#> 6  K1 2020-10-12 07:37:19      <NA>      <NA>
#> 7  KK 2020-10-13 08:11:09 KK-081109    create
#> 8  KK 2020-10-13 08:11:09 KK-081109    create
#> 9  KK 2020-10-13 08:11:12 KK-081109    upload
#> 10 KK 2020-10-13 08:11:15      <NA>      <NA>
#> 11 KK 2020-10-13 08:11:25 KK-081125    create
#> 12 KK 2020-10-13 08:11:26 KK-081125    upload
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>